# C++ Sockets - Sending messages with new line (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am trying to send messages from client to server and vice versa. The messages are receiving correctly but I have to put an `*` at the end of every message.

The control loop I am using is `*buffer != '*'`. I tried to replace with `\n` or checking with via ASCII value which is 10 through `static_cast` but the message is not going.

How do I transfer messages when the user enters a new line (\n). I am thinking of `cin.getline`. is it okay to use it with a pointer?

server.cpp

```
     do {
            recv(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
            cout << buffer << " ";
            if (*buffer == '#') {
                *buffer = '*';
                isExit = true;
            }
        } while (*buffer != '*');

        do {
            cout << "\nServer: ";
            do {
                cin >> buffer;
                send(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
                if (*buffer == '#') {
                    send(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
                    *buffer = '*';
                    isExit = true;
                }
            } while (*buffer != '*');

            cout << "Client: ";
            do {
                recv(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
                cout << buffer << " ";
                if (*buffer == '#') {
                    *buffer == '*';
                    isExit = true;
                }
            } while (*buffer != '*');
        } while (!isExit);
```

client.cpp

```
     do {
        cout << "Client: ";
        do {
            cin >> buffer;
            send(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
            if (*buffer == '#') {
                send(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
                *buffer = '*';
                isExit = true;
            }
        } while (*buffer != 42);

        cout << "Server: ";
        do {
            recv(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
            cout << buffer << " ";
            if (*buffer == '#') {
                *buffer = '*';
                isExit = true;
            }

        } while (*buffer != 42);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You throw away the return value of `recv`, so you have no idea how many bytes you received! How is `cou << buffer << " ";` supposed to know how many bytes to output?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When it sees the null character (\0) at the end of the char pointer, it will output it?

Comment: You're inside `do`/`while` loop, and no code inside that loop puts a null character anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only examining the first character of the buffer. You need to either read one byte at a time (yuck) or scan the entire buffer for the delimiter.

Note that it might be in the middle, before part or all of another message.

Comment: So I have to get the ASCII value of "\" and "n" as well?? How do I scan the "entire buffer". cin.getline(buffer, 1024); ?